# Saltstack apply state on minions through salt reactors and runners

Tags: salt-stack

I have multiple salt deployment environments.
I have a requirement in which I raise an event from the minions, the master upon receiving the event, generates few files which I then want to copy to the minions.
How do I do this?
I was trying to get it to work using orchestrate. This is what I have right now:

reactor sls->

```
copy_cert:
  runner.state.orchestrate:
    - mods: _orch.copy_certs
    - saltenv: 'central'
```

copy_certs sls->

```
copy_kube_certs:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: 'kubeminion'
    - tgt_type: nodegroup
    - sls:
      - kubemaster.copy_certs
```

The problem is that I want to happen for all the environments and not just one. How do I do that?
Or is there a way to loop over the environments using jinja in some way.
Also is it possible using anything other than orchestrate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use orchestrate for this, all you need is the salt reactor.

Lets say you fire an event from the minion `salt-call event.send tag='event/test'` (you can watch the salt event bus using `salt-run state.event pretty=True`):

```
event/test      {
    "_stamp": "2017-05-24T10:36:05.907438",
    "cmd": "_minion_event",
    "data": {
        "__pub_fun": "event.send",
        "__pub_jid": "20170524133601757005",
        "__pub_pid": 4590,
        "__pub_tgt": "salt-call"
    },
    "id": "minion_A",
    "tag": "event/test"
}
```

Now you need to decide what happens when salt receives the event, edit/create /etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf (remember to restart the salt-master after editing this file):

```
reactor:
  - event/test:  # event tag to match
    - /srv/reactor/some_state.sls  # sls file to run
```

some_state.sls:

```
some_state:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: kubeminion
    - tgt_type: nodegroup
    - arg:
      - kubemaster.copy_certs
    - kwarg:
      - saltenv: central
```

This will in turn apply the state `kubemaster.copy_certs` to all minions in the "kubeminion" nodegroup.

Hope this helps.